# OpenCart can't add or edit product

Tags: php, opencart

My OpenCart version 1.5.6 and I'm not using vQmod.
So recently I added one custom product field. This tutorial helped me to do that
http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=36625#p181916
Now, when I'm trying to add a new product to store this error appears:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelCatalogCategory::getAllCategories() in C:\apache\localhost\www\webshop.kg\admin\controller\catalog\product.php on line 1018
```

If I'm trying to edit already existing product these two errors appear:

```
Notice: Undefined index: seo_title in C:\apache\localhost\www\webshop.kg\admin\model\catalog\product.php on line 456Notice: Undefined index: seo_h1 in C:\apache\localhost\www\webshop.kg\admin\model\catalog\product.php on line 457
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelCatalogCategory::getAllCategories() in C:\apache\localhost\www\webshop.kg\admin\controller\catalog\product.php on line 1018
```

What possible reason could create such a behavior?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Provide your model file code - this is why vQmod is such a good idea. You can make edits, and just remove them if they don't work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within your controller as the model in `admin/model/catalog/category.php` **does not contain** a method **`getAllCategories()`** (unless you added it there which is not a case because of the **fatal error**) - it contains only the method **`getCategories()`**.

Furthermore your *Undefined index* notices are saying that within your product model (lines `456` and `457`) you are relying on the presence of the indexes `seo_title` and `seo_h1` but they are not set.

I do not know the code you have modified in `admin/model/catalog/product.php` but you should use something like this:

```
if(isset($data['seo_title'])) { /* do setting of seo title */ } /* else { do not set this } */
if(isset($data['seo_h1'])) { /* do setting of seo h1 */ } /* else { do not set this } */
```

Maybe posting the method reliable for storing new or updating existing product code would be more helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The model in admin/model/catalog/category.php does not contain a method getAllCategories(). So you need to define it in category model.

```
public function getAllCateories() {
    $query = "WRITE YOUR QUERY";
}
```